# Consulta con mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Deseo llamar todos los nombres de una colección 'users' sin la información que lo acompañe, la consulta que hago me trae toda la información que se encuentra en la colección 'users' (nombre, apellido, contraseña) y quisiera solo llamar los nombres excluyendo apellido y contraseña, es posible?

```
    router.get('/getusers',getTypeUser, (req,res) => {
      const Users = require('../models/users');
      Users.find({typeuser:res.typeUser}).exec(function(err, Users ){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error");
    }else{
      res.json(Users);
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si te he entendido bien, lo que quieres hacer es traer en el select solo el nombre?.
`.find()` ,admite como segundo parámetro los campos que quieres.

```
  router.get('/getusers',getTypeUser, (req,res) => {
      const Users = require('../models/users');
      Users.find({typeuser:res.typeUser},'nombre').exec(function(err, Users ){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error");
    }else{
      res.json(Users);
    }
  })
})
```